# Lightroom Classic CC crashes when using another disk as home folder

Tags: lightroom, macintosh

## The Issue

I'm running Lightroom Classic CC on my iMac, and have recently split the Fusion drive into its SSD and HDD components so that system files and applications sit isolated on the SSD for speed purposes.

I followed [this guide](https://www.lifewire.com/move-macs-home-folder-new-location-2260157) to make the change, and everything other than Lightroom has worked without issues. Lightroom, however, crashes immediately after showing the splash screen, and doesn't give any clear error messages in Console or otherwise.

I can confirm that restoring my user folder on the SSD (which has now been cloned to the HDD) makes Lightroom work again, but I don't want to keep the entire folder on my SSD for the sake of disk space consumed.

Does anyone know why this happens, and why Lightroom seems to ignore my re-allocated home folder?

## System Information

[image: macOS system information]
[image: Lightroom system information]

Answer (score 3):

Lightroom Classic CC seems to depend on the existence of the `/Users/{username}/Documents` directory, and creates an empty `Adobe` directory within that upon launch.

Making sure that this `Documents` folder exists fixes the crash issue, with no storage space used or disk performance issues (in my case).